# Fixed DIV does not obey z-index

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-position

We have a screen that looks similar to the below:

```
----------------------------
| Fixed Nav     | Fixed    |
----------------| side bar |
| App content   | with     |
|               | icons    |
----------------------------
```

when a user selects an icon on the right, a side panel scrolls right to left with extra details in it.

However, the issue we are having is that when the side content bar scrolls onto the screen it cover the `Fixed sidebar with icons`. The `icons` themselves are above the `side content bar`, but the base bar is below.

```css
.application-container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.top-nav-container {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-nav-spacer {
  height: 30px;
}

.portal-content {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.portal-view {
  height: 100%;
}

.app-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 46px);
  background-color: aqua;
}

.nav-side-bar {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 46px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
}

.side-bar-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

.side-bar-icon-container {
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  background-color:brown;
}

.side-bar-content {
  right: -500px;
  
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(100% - 63px);
  top: 0px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.99;
  
  -webkit-transition: right 1s;
  -moz-transition: right 1s;
  -o-transition: right 1s;
  transition: right 1s;
}

.side-bar-icon-container:hover + .side-bar-content {
  right: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="application-container">
  <div class="portal-nav">
    <div class="top-nav-container">Nav items</div>
    <div class="top-nav-spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portal-content">
    <div class="portal-view">
      <section class="app-content">
        App content
      </section>
      <section class="nav-side-bar">
        <div class="side-bar-container">
          <div class="side-bar-icon-container">
            <ul>
              <li>Icon 1</li>
              <li>Icon 2</li>
            </ul>
            Hover over this area for the slide in
          </div>
          <div class="side-bar-content">
            Content to slide in
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The fixed nav items have `z-index` values associated, but the sliding div does not appear to be obeying all the `z-index` values to have been set.

How does one get the side bar to appear from behind the `fixed side bar`?

Comment: maybe i don't understand correctly. in the fiddle the grey sidebar ( that appears on hover ) is under the redish sidebar with icons. Isn't that what you want ? ( tested in Chrome, FF and IE )

Comment: @MihaiT Yes - it goes under the `brown` bar - but only under the `brown` bar and the white area is covered by the grey when it slides in - i.e. I would like the bar to "appear" from under the whole bar. Because there are icons the whole bar is not "full" so the `brown` section is just an indication of where the icons would be.

Comment: Or, better yet, don't link to 3rd party sites at all and include a code snippet right into your question.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the two elements existing in two different **[stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)**, which are determined by the HTML organization. Reworking the HTML to have both elements existing within the same common parent often solves this issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus True - I've just seen many other questions doing the same thing, so thought it was a given that people liked the idea. I'll follow that advice next time :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus re - stacking - that's what I thought as well, so they have 2 common parents `section class="nav-side-bar"` and `div class="side-bar-container"`. So both have the parents, and the parents have `z-index` set, so not sure where the error is with stacking...

Comment: Read the link I shared. Your `fixed` element is creating its own stacking context. You'd need your other elements to be in that same parent as the `fixed` element.